# Integrate Google Classroom in Android App

Tags: android, api

We work from home now in my university and we now rely heavily on the Google Classroom platform. The Google classroom Android app provided by Google in the PlayStore is so poor and sucks alot. The Android System always shows **Classroom has stopped** no matter how many times we uninstall, reinstall clear it's data etc. I haven't found any app as poor as it is. We all resort to accessible it through a Web browser which ain't convenient for accessing our work offline.

As a developer, I decided it wouldn't be much of an overhead implementing a Google Classroom Android App for use in my university. I looked at the [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started), there isn't any option for **Android**.

Anyone could please provide help on how to get this done? I hate to think it's impossible!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they would need to provide anything specific to Android, if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java) they provide a Java Classroom library that you should be able to use in an Android project.

The specific dependency is this one:

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-classroom:v1-rev135-1.23.0`

Comment: Hey bro you there, after several hours of trying with no positive I saw this link https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/thread/60299138?hl=en      and it says it's impossible any tip about it?